# Is There Any Capacity or Security matter With Class Formats?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, private, protected

I Know the Difference between Public/Private/Protected/Static and other Formats of class.
But It's my Question.Is there any matter with security or Capacity of File for using Public?
If is not...Why do not always use Public?

What is The usage?

in Fact i have problem with reflection to other Class which methods are private or protected.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “capacity”?

Answer (score 1):

`public`, `protected`, `internal`, `protected internal`, and `private` are all access modifiers.

> Why do not always use Public?

These keywords, including `public` are used to restrict access and show "intention" of how they should be used.

If I decide to make a class `public`, I am stating that this class is reusable and access to it should not be restricted.

On the otherside of that, if I mark a class as `private`, I am showing my intention that this class should not be used outside of my containing type.

These are two cases.

For more information, here is a reference: [MSDN - Accessibility Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)